# MATCH errors with 438

Tags: vba, excel

I can't get MATCH to work, please help!
I keep getting error 438 at the last line...
With only one data point after the header defined, the 'row' value becomes 2, and the loc gets set as "A1:A2".

Thanks in advance!

```
Dim loc As String
Dim row As Integer
Dim value As Integer

'Get current max rows in table
row = Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.count
'Define the range as being all of A column to end of data
loc = "A1:A" & row

'lookFor is defined previously as some value to search for
value = ActiveSheet.Match(lookFor, ActiveSheet.range(loc), 0)
```

Comment: what is in your `lookFor` variable?

Comment: How are you handling if lookFor doesn't exist in the given range? I believe Match will throw an error if lookFor isn't found. You can avoid this by Dimming value as an object rather than an int. This way value will get a #N/A if the lookFor value isn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ActiveSheet.Match` to `Application.Match`:

```
value = Application.Match(lookFor, ActiveSheet.Range(loc), 0)
```

**First tip:** don't use variables with special VBA names like `value` and `row`. Use something like this instead `myValue` and `lastrow`.

**Second tip:** if `Match` found nothing, it returns error. To handle it, use this code:

```
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = ActiveSheet.Match(lookFor, ActiveSheet.Range(loc), 0)

If Not IsError(myValue) Then
    'do sth
End If
```

**Third tip:** if you need to find last non empty row in column `A`, I suggest you to use

```
Dim lastRow as Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

instead

```
row = Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.count
```

**Note** that I declared `lastRow as Long`. Using `Integer` for row variable is bad idea, because maximum value of `Integer` only `32767`.

For more information about finding last row see [**this @SiddharthRout's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: Thanks!  Using Application instead of ActiveSheet did the trick.

Comment: I clicked the 'check' mark, but since I'm a newbie here, won't let me click on the 'Vote up" icon..